# C# Regex - Match expression that does not start with a specific word

Tags: c#, regex, replace, find

I have read similar questions but I can't get this to work. I want to use the regex for the Find-Replace Visual Studio tool that supports C# regular expressions.

I want to find (and replace with nothing) expressions such as:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
```

And remove `System.Collections.Generic.` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls` to tidy my code up.

BUT I want the ability to add new words after 'System.' to the expression if I want to scale it. So I have created this:

`(System\.)?(Collections\.)?(Generic\.)?(Web\.)?(UI\.)?(WebControls\.)?`

However, this also changes using statements such as:

`using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Is there a way to alter my regular expression so that it does not include matches that start with the "using" keyword?

I have tried using:

`(^?!using)(System\.)?(Collections\.)?(Generic\.)?(Web\.)?(UI\.)?(WebControls\.)?`

but this does not work. Thanks!

Comment: `Imports` is VB.Net, in C# it is `using`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. The regular expressions supported in Visual Studio find-replace use the same syntax regardless of the content being searched for. "Imports" is just the word I want to find. The question could have been to find "fapojapof" and would have been the same problem.

Comment: I replaced "Imports" with "using" though to clear things up. I usually use this find-replace regex expression in both types of projects (c# and vb).

Comment: Does `^(System\.)?(Collections\.)?(Generic\.)?(Web\.)?(UI\.)?(WebControls\.)?/` work properly for your case ?

Comment: @Leyffda sadly not because that relies on the line starting with "System" but it might be something like: `var a = new System.Collections.Generic.List();` which does not get selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using negative lookbehind, to assert match is not preceeded by `using`

[`(?<!^using )`](https://regex101.com/r/WRqiTt/1)

However as all parts are optionnal it will match `Collections.` in

```
using System.Collection.Generic.List
```

Which may be not wanted, also many regex engine have a limitation lookbehinds can't have a variable length match.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have will allow for partial matching. Try specifying that "using" must appear 0 times. ^(using){0}

If that doesn't work, you can do the following:
1.Find and replace "using system" with "usingsistem". 
2. Find and replace system.whatever. 
3. Find and replace "usingsistem" with "using system"